# Are there any substances that allow sound to travel better then air?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves

The question is the same as the one I put in the title but here it is in more words.

I was wondering if there were any substances that allowed sound to travel more efficiently. For example water is obviously a much worse way to transport sound then air.

Comment: I just have to mentioned all those westerns where people listen to approaching trains by laying they ear against the metal (iron?) tracks.

Comment: Maybe I'm just missing something obvious, but what exactly do you mean by "travel more efficiently" and "travel better"?

Comment: Define efficient here. If you are talking about speed, it moves quicker in solids than air.

Comment: I guess I'm kind of unsure what I mean by this. An example i can give that might make this more understandable is if you had a vacuum and were looking to transport sound waves over a large distance what material would you want to use to do that?

Comment: I'd use electromagnetic radiation... :) Quick and Cheap.

Comment: @ArachnidHivemind, So, do you mean what substances will allow a sound of a given initial intensity to have the largest final intensity over a given distance?

Comment: I'm curious about what makes you think that water is "obviously" inferior to air as a sound transport medium? I suspect what you are actually thinking about is how ill-suited the human vocal system is to driving sound in water...

Comment: A lot depends on dimensions. If the medium is fully 3d over long distances, energy falls off as $1/r^2$. If it's 2d, like a temperature layer in air or water, it is $1/r$, so sound can carry a lot farther. If it's 1d, like a tin-can string, pipe, or iron rail, the sound can go very far without dissipating.

Answer (score 2):

Since your criterion is efficiency (least loss of transmitted power over distance), you want some medium that is nicely elastic and doesn't have inherent losses due to compression and expansion.

Something reasonably incompressible and elastic sounds like it would to best.  Spring steel comes to mind.  Water should also be pretty good because it is not that compressible.  Water is much less compressible than hydrolic fluid, for example.  I have no idea why you think water would be worse than air.  I don't have any hard numbers, but I would expect water to be better than any gas.  It's certainly not "obvious" to me at all why water should be a less efficient transport of sound energy than air, even if it ultimately is so (which I doubt).

Something squishy that is inelastic would do poorly, as should be obvious intuitively.  A piece of foam rubber, for example, transmits sound very poorly.

Answer (score 1):

> **Are there any substances that allow sound to travel better then air?**

This depends on

- what sound or sort of sound?
- in what way better?

When I was a young boy, all young boys had experimentally verified that taut string was a very good conductor of sound between two tin cans. The more adventurous and foolhardy ones verified that extremely long welded steel I-beams resting on wooden supports on a gravel bed were pretty good too.

> **water is obviously a much worse way to transport sound then air.**

Whales would disagree. From their perspective, water is a much better carrier of whale song.

Whale songs have been recorded at a distance of 100 miles.

Comment: + Air isn't so bad either, at low frequencies.